# npm install bluebird doesn't install module

Tags: npm, installation, bluebird

I am attempting to use [bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird) in a node application. I have tried adding bluebird to my package.json, as well as installing via `npm install bluebird`.

My package.json dependencies:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "visionmedia/express",
    "mocha": "visionmedia/mocha",
    "bluebird": "petkaantonov/bluebird",
    "waitjs": "elving/wait"
  }
```

Regardless of what method I try, it doesn't look like the module is actually being installed. After I run the install; in node_modules\bluebird there are only 4 files:

- changelog.md
- LICENSE
- package.json
- READEME.md

As you can see, there is no code pulled down which would actually comprise the module. The package.json for bluebird does not have a dependencies section, so I am not sure if maybe the package.json file for the module is incorrect?

I've pasted the [package.json](http://pastebin.com/FkTdk2Ue) contents on pastebin for easier viewing.

I'm pretty stumped why this is not installing correctly.

npm version: 2.11.3.
node version: v0.12.7.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dependencies section of the packages.json should have version numbers as the module values, not git repos.

If you are having this issue, remove your dependcies section from package.json and then install each module using `npm install {module name} -save`.

My package.json ended up looking like:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "bluebird": "^2.9.34",
    "express": "^4.13.1",
    "mocha": "^2.2.5",
    "waitjs": "^0.2.0"
  }
```

Thanks to [untogethered](https://www.reddit.com/r/node/comments/3enpcc/npm_install_bluebird_doesnt_install_module/ctgncwn) on reddit for the answer.

Comment: Note that you can, in fact, also install from a github tag or repo directly.

Comment: How would one setup their package.json to install from a git repo directly? When using the "petkaantonov/bluebird" value, the module was not installing fully.

Comment: @Ronburgundy The problem is that Bluebird has a `prepublish` script and only files that are built by that script are listed in `files`.  When you install from Github, it doesn't run the `prepublish` script but does respect `files`, none of which exist.

Answer (score 0):

First thing to always try with module install problems is:

```
npm cache clean
```

Then try and install again, also remember to remove the bad install at node_modules/bluebird